# How to reference relative path of an element in a subfolder from another subfolder in VScode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have an image in a folder "image" and my html page in another folder "Source-Code". How can I provide the link of the image in my html page as a relative path and not absolute path.

[image]

**Note:

1. The html page is inside another folder so please provide your suggestions accordingly.
2. Simply copying the relative path of the image is not working.
3. I dont need the absolute path (as i need to transfer the code so the absolute path will keep on changing)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two dots (eg "../") to go up one directory and then you can access your images directory to get the image.

```
<img src="../images/imgname.png">
```